# Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable in python3

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, django-2.2

My Code is

```
configfile = open("abc.txt",'rb').read()
return base64.b64encode(configfile)
```

got error "Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable in python3.6" on ec2

Answer (score 0):

Above issue appeared when i updated  Django 1.8 to Django 2.2.6

I solve this by

Consider installing and using [simplejson][1], which can handle bytes strings in addition to unicode, to install it use command below:

```
pip3 install simplejson
```

Usage in code:

```
import simplejson as json

json.dumps({b'name': b'dev'})
```

This will solve  JSON serializable issue.